# How hide Arrows in mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, gallery

Check please: https://iconsmgmt.com/project/miguel-ferrero/

If you see in the mobile version, the arrows are fixed on the image. How arrows  only appear when the cursor is in the photo, just like the desktop version. I use wordpress/divi.

A CSS expert could help me. 
Thanks you.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask We need to see your code and what you tried. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in mobile version for better ux, the arrows should appear by default. but if you want arrows behave like desktop, you should do this:
in the css file you have these code, you should omit the "opacity:1" from them.

```
@media all and (max-width:767px) {
   .et_mobile_device .et-pb-arrow-prev {
       left: 0;
       opacity:1; // omit this line
   }
   .et_mobile_device .et-pb-arrow-next {
        right: 0;
        opacity: 1; // omit this line
   }
}
```

and this:

```
.et_mobile_device .et-pb-arrow-prev {
    left: 22px;
    opacity:1; // omit this line
}

.et_mobile_device .et-pb-arrow-next {
    right: 22px;
    opacity: 1; // omit this line
}
```

Comment: Not work for me...I need the arrows only appear when the cursor is in the photo, not always.. Or hide them definitely if there is no other remedy.

Comment: do you find the css and remove the opacity?
add this code :
    @media all and (max-width:767px) {
       .et_mobile_device .et-pb-arrow-prev {
           left: 0;
           opacity:0;
       }
       .et_mobile_device .et-pb-arrow-next {
            right: 0;
            opacity: 0;
       }
      .et_pb_slider:hover .et-pb-arrow-next {
           right: -10px;
           opacity: 1;
       }
      .et_pb_slider:hover .et-pb-arrow-prev {
           left: -10px;
           opacity: 1;
       }
    }